# Close javascript popup Oracle forms

Tags: javascript, webdriver, sikuli

I am working on a project using Sikuli and web-driver to automate testing of Oracle forms using Chrome as the browser.

It works well but at the end of each test when shutting down the browser i get prompted with the following:

Confirm Navigation
Incorrect method of closing form. Any unsaved changes will be lost....
Are you sure you want to leave this page?

Is there a way to suppress this popup using chromium flags?  Webdriver cannot by default handle the javascript popup.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a javascript alert, then you can use the Alert class in Webdriver. Refer [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Q%3a_Does_WebDriver_support_Javascript_alerts_and_prompts?). Otherwise you can use Sikuli to close the popup.